# How to test email spoofing with this php script?

Tags: php, python, email-spoofing

I want to harden my SPF setting.

However I have trouble testing my SPF setting.

I want to be able send a test email to try out my new SPF settings.

Most of the resource on internet seems to be use a similar php script, which looks something like this:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

(The above comes from the website here: https://dylan.tweney.com/2017/10/25/how-to-fake-an-email-from-almost-anyone-in-under-5-minutes/)

I am not familiar with php at all. When I run it on my macbookpro, it throws this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$subject' (T_VARIABLE) in /Users/antkong/myproject/_test_mail/test.php on line 5
```

Here is the command: `php -n -f test.php`

and the version of my php run time is

```
$ php -version
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:19:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

My questions:

1. What do I need to run this php script successfully?
2. I don't need to stick to php. I am happy to use other language such as python. I wonder if there is a counterpart of the php script above written in python or other language which is easier to set up and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code there. What you're getting is a code compile error, and your code is syntactically fine.

I'm running your code just dumping the variables rather than trying to send an email:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
string(18) "nobody@example.com"
string(11) "the subject"
string(5) "hello"
string(29) "From: webmaster@example.com
"
```

I can make a similar error appear by removing one of the semicolons from the code as such:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com' //removed semicolon here
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$subject' (T_VARIABLE) in F:\test.php on line 3
```

Which even in itself is different from the "error in line 5" you're getting. My suggestion is that you're not running the code you think you are. Double check `test.php` and go from there.